# Change the div to be scrolled to after click?

Tags: jquery, scrollto

I have a set of three pages where I am using ScrollTo to navigate. The issue I am having is that I need page 2 to be a static page but page 1 and page 3 to run an ajax call when they are scrolled to?

I have a jsfiddle here: h[ttp://jsfiddle.net/xYaPF/](http://jsfiddle.net/xYaPF/)

The simple solution would be to do something like this : http://jsfiddle.net/UaGjs/506/ but I can't see how to ensure the ajax gets called properly?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 moveRight.click(function(evt) {
     $('#Mpage').scrollTo('#Right', 500);
       //Do your ajax call for page 3
    $.ajax(
         //your parameter
      )

});

 moveLeft.click(function(evt) {
     $('#Mpage').scrollTo('#Left', 500);

         //Do your ajax call for page 1
    $.ajax(
         //your parameter
      )

});
```

**UPDATE**

[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7BE9g/)

```
$(function(){
    $('#Mpage').scrollTo('#MainPage', 0 ); 
    });    


    $(function(){

        var moveRight = $('#main_nav a.next');
        var moveLeft = $('#main_nav a.prev');

         var flag=true;
         moveRight.click(function(evt) {
             if(flag){
             $('#Mpage').scrollTo('#Right', 500);
                 flag=false;
             }
             else{flag=true;
              $('#Mpage').scrollTo('#MainPage',500 );   
             }

        });

         moveLeft.click(function(evt) {
             if(flag){
             $('#Mpage').scrollTo('#Left', 500);flag=false;
             }
             else
             {flag=true;
             $('#Mpage').scrollTo('#MainPage',500 ); 
             }



        });
```

Comment: How do I move back to the home page. Sorry if my initial explanation sucked, The issue isn't how to make the ajax call but in how to navigate? How can the user move to page 3 and page 1 and trigger the ajax but also navigate back to page 2 or the home page?

Comment: can not youuse a button to scroll him back to home page?

Comment: That seems less efficient? The left and right buttons are currently static on the page, they don't move with the scroll, I would like to, alter the div to which the button is set to scroll dependent on the users current page location? i.e. if the user is on page 1, the next button will scroll to page 2 instead of page 3 has the code currently does.